# Twitter API change header or background

Tags: api, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I have 0.0% experience with the Twitter API.

However, I was wondering, if it's possible, using this API or some other method, to have my Header or Background change everytime someone reloaded my Twitter page,

https://twitter.com/Otanan

My goal, or ideal method is someone just loads my Bio and it randomly selects an Image from a folder I have somewhere, or whatever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.  The Twitter APIs, as they currently stand, seem to be designed for someone to change the page from a non-twitter application.  Twitter won't let people run executable code in other people's browsers as it would open the gateway to huge numbers of viruses.

So, no, it isn't possible

Comment: Ended up just creating a timer that changes my Twitter header every ~5 seconds, thank you!